# CSS centering on desktop but not mobile

Tags: css, mobile

I have been hunting around and haven't found a solution that works yet.

Here is my site which does what is needed on a desktop but when it loads in mobile the upper icons are no longer centered but the lower ones are

To supply all the code here would be long so I'm sure someone will knock me for that but to me it seems easy to use the inspector since i'm not sure if css else where could be effecting this.
I will gladly paste all of the code here if really needed.

As you can see on the desktop they are in a row but on a mobile I would like to have them centered and 2 in a row on portrait and all in a line on landscape but still be centered in the screen.

[My Site Desktop](http://dbvinyls.com/Home.html)

[My Site in an iPhone 5 view](http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/#u=http://dbvinyls.com/home.html)

Comment: Does the class `.centermiddle` have a max width?

Comment: @Fraggy .centermiddle has no set width.

Comment: @chdtest answer should do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your div `.centermiddle` you have divs named `.view` that have the style `float: left;`

Instead of floating your elements you should set them as `display: inline-block;` which is the correct way of achieving what you want to do.

Doing so will center those buttons for you.